# Can I prevent one friend from posting on my profile in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I have one person on my friend list that I would like to prevent from writing on my wall.  Is there a way to do this in Facebook?

Comment: Ha!  You seem to have the reverse problem that I do!  http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3312/facebook-friend-list-members-unable-to-post-on-wall

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like it.

If you customise your privacy settings there is an option to allow *all* friends to post on your wall, but it doesn't have the ability to specify individual friends or a list of friends.