# Facebook "friend list" members unable to post on wall

Tags: facebook, privacy

Prior to a lot of the privacy redesign changes that have been going on with Facebook, I had a specific set of friends grouped into a friend list.  For this list, I restricted access so that these members could not post on my wall.

Since the privacy redesign several months ago, Facebook removed the ability to granularly toggle this setting.  I'd like these members to be able to post on my wall now, and despite the setting being gone, they are still prevented from posting.  As you can see below, I have globally enabled wall posting.

[image: Wall setting]

To me, it is like Facebook removed the ability to set the option, but didn't remove the database and code that reads the setting.  There doesn't appear to be a toggle, and I'd rather not have to go through each member, remove them from the current list, and add them to a similarly named new list.

Anybody have any ideas on how I can toggle this behavior?

Comment: Did you try to uncheck that option, save, then check the option, then save again?

Comment: The global setting in the image?  Yes, I have.  Doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to report the bug on [this page](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=1000). Probably use the third option from the bottom called "I've set the privacy of some of my content to "Everyone", but it's not visible to everyone." If you don't have access to the setting and you know moving users out of the list and into a new one works, then that might be your best options rather than waiting.

Comment: That option if you click on it appears to be specifically for photos.  I did use the last option, which is this form http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=1000#!/help/contact.php?show_form=updated_privacy_bug , but haven't received a response.

Comment: go straight to the source support@facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

I think they removed this feature. See [Question 3309](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3309/can-i-prevent-one-friend-from-posting-on-my-profile-in-facebook) for the opposite of this question.

Comment: I understand that they removed the feature.  Except that they didn't fully remove it because the members of this list are still restricted by the former setting.